# The difference between a Tor file on linux and a Tor file on windows

Tags: windows, compilation, cygwin, tor

I'm testing few things in Tor source code-adding nodes and missing nodes. in Linux when im changing the source code i need to use:

Terminal

for compiling the new code that i created. i'm doing that in terminal for creating a new "tor" file that's containing my new code with this commend:

```
./configure && make
```

after that commend finished i need to move the new "Tor" file from the source code folder to the folder in Tor-Browser. as i said i want to cause Tor work as i want. in Linux environment- after moving the new "Tor" file from source code folder to the Tor-Browesr folder its working great- as i wanted.

But, when i'm doing this in Windows environment(in the same way as i did in Linux) i want to compile those files as i did in Linux; that's why i'm using:

Cygwin64 Terminal

the re-compile went great without any error's. i have the new "tor.exe" file in Tor's source code folder, now i'm moving the new "Tor.exe" file to Tor-browser folder exactly as i did in Linux. but, im having problems with that when i'm opening the Tor-Browser- i get the photo(in the end of this post) and nothing help's, even press "restart tor" button.

[image]

Comment: have you closed all "*tor*" processes ?

Comment: @matzeri Yes i did.

Comment: @matzeri hope its more clear now

Comment: If you compile Tor within Cygwin, you are building the target for Cygwin.  It will not run in Windows as a Windows binary.  You instead need to build with MinGW if you want to build a Windows version of Tor.  I wasn't quickly able to find updated build instructions for Tor on Windows from the tor source.

Comment: @drew010 Thank you very much! Im looking for too(have not find any) if you will find i hope you will post it here.